# Joomla jQuery menu item attribute

Tags: jquery, joomla, menu, menuitem

Has anyone successfully retrieved an attribute from a Joomla menu item? I need to capture this attribute into jQuery.
In the page source the menu, in part, shows up like this:

```
     < ul class="menudirectory">  
    < li class="item-182" >< a title="services" href = "/index.php/services">Services< /a>< /li>  
    < li class="item-183">< a title="education" href="/index.php/education">Education< /a>< /li>  
    < /ul>
```

I tried various selectors like

```
jQuery( 'ul.menudirectory' ) .attr ( 'title' );
```

or

```
jQuery( '.menudirectory a' ) .attr ( 'title' );
```

and all I ever get is 'services' which is the first menu item, or 'undefined' as a result.

PS Starting to get there. I tried this:

```
jQuery('.menudirectory a').click(function () {  
      var theid = jQuery(this).get();
```

And I am getting the href attribute. Close.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this:

```
$('a','ul.menudirectory').attr('title');
```

**Edit**:
The above line means `$("elementToSearch", "Context")`

Where as if I had written `$("a, ul.menudirectory")`, it would have meant OR. 
Notice the comma is within quotation marks in second line

Comment: I have seen the usage of a comma in the selector before and that totally confuses me. To me a comma would mean 'OR'

Comment: Perfectly answered, thank you so much. The above information has all worked just fine in my application.

Comment: @GAHiebert well, good to know. You should mark this answer as correct